# How to share state when using concurrent futures

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-multiprocessing, python-multithreading

I am aware using the traditional multiprocessing library I can declare a value and share the state between processes.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html?highlight=multiprocessing#sharing-state-between-processes

When using the newer `concurrent.futures` library how can I share state between my processes?

```
import concurrent.futures

def get_user_object(batch):
    # do some work
    counter = counter + 1
    print(counter)

def do_multithreading(batches):
    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=25) as executor:
        threadingResult = executor.map(get_user_object, batches)

def run():
    data_pools = get_data()
    start = time.time()
    with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=PROCESSES) as executor:
        processResult = executor.map(do_multithreading, data_pools)
    end = time.time()
    print("TIME TAKEN:", end - start)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    run()
```

I want to keep a synchronized value of this counter.

In the previous library I might have used `multiprocessing.Value` and a `Lock`.

Comment: this is specifically related to the new concurrent.fututres library

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can pass an `initializer` and `initargs` to `ProcessPoolExecutor` just as you would to `multiprocessing.Pool`.  Here's an example:

```
import concurrent.futures
import multiprocessing as mp


def get_user_object(batch):
    with _COUNTER.get_lock():
        _COUNTER.value += 1
        print(_COUNTER.value, end=' ')


def init_globals(counter):
    global _COUNTER
    _COUNTER = counter


def main():
    counter = mp.Value('i', 0)
    with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(
        initializer=init_globals, initargs=(counter,)
    ) as executor:
        for _ in executor.map(get_user_object, range(10)):
            pass
    print()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    sys.exit(main())
```

Use:

```
$ python3 glob_counter.py 
1 2 4 3 5 6 7 8 10 9
```

Where:

- `for _ in executor.map(get_user_object, range(10)):` lets you iterate over each **result**.  In this case, `get_user_object()` returns `None`, so you don't really have anything to process; you just `pass` and take no further action.
- The last `print()` call gives you an extra newline, because the original `print()` call does not use a newline (`end=' '`')

Comment: What is the empty print at the end and the for_ in pass doing?

Comment: Added some details @Kay

Comment: maybe a similar question you could help with...https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56092001/how-to-share-a-synchronised-list-of-classes-between-processes-in-python-multipro